# Is there a way to cancel/stop an instance of `contract.once(...)` listening to events?

Tags: web3js

I have a function in my smart contract that fires an event, which i am listening for to react in my dapp:

```
 this.Worker.onmessage = function (msg) {
            var data = msg.data.transactionData;

config.smartContract.once(
                'DataProcessed',
                {
                    filter: {
                        sender: config.account,
                        data: data,
                    },
                    fromBlock: 0,
                },
                function (error, event) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        console.log(event);

                        alertify.success('Data stored on the blockchain was a success!');

                   } else {
                        console.log(error);
                        alertify.error('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                }
            );

 config.smartContract.methods
                .setData(data)
                .send({ from: config.account })
                .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
                    console.log('Got receipt data from transaction: ' + receipt);
                    alertify.success('Receipt '+receipt);
                })
                .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
                    console.log('Got confirmation from transaction: ' + confirmationNumber + ' - ' + receipt);
                })
                .on('error', function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    if (error.message.indexOf('User denied') != -1) {
                        alertify.error('You rejected the transaction on Metamask!');
                    } else {
                        alertify.error('Sorry, the transaction failed: ' + error.name + ' - ' + error.message);
                    }
                });
```

As you can see this `config.smartContract.once(...)` event listener is setup inside a worker at the point the worker finishes processing the data, however if the user cancels the transaction and makes another one, the previously setup "once" is still active, waiting for the event (I see multiple instances of the logs/alertify messages when the transaction succeeds after rejecting a few times). How can i nullify/cancel any existing `once(...)` observers?

Comment: Are you working with node? In that case notifications seems to be based [node's events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener), perhaps removeListener will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html#id36) on `send(...)` I found there is a `transactionHash` you can listen out for:

> "transactionHash" returns String: is fired right after the transaction is sent and a transaction hash is available.

So rather than creating the transaction and the event listener at the same time, I am creating the `config.smartContract.once(...)` observer inside `.on('transactionHash', ...)` at which point we know the transaction is confirmed and being sent to the blockchain as it has a hash:

```
                .setData(data)
                .send({ from: config.account })
                .on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {
                     config.smartContract.once(
                       'DataProcessed',
                        {
                           filter: {
                           sender: config.account,
                           data: data,
                           },
                         fromBlock: 0,
                       },
                function (error, event) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        console.log(event);

                        alertify.success('Data stored on the blockchain was a success!');

                   } else {
                        console.log(error);
                        alertify.error('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                }
            );
    });
```

This approach solves my problem as the event listener is only created when I know there is definitely a transaction happening.